# Misere nim variant

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, nim

Is there a name (and strategy) for this nim variant?

There are $n$ lists of objects, say $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ where $L_i = \{a_{i,1},a_{i,2},\ldots,a_{i,n_i}\}$. Players take turns choosing a list and any number of *sequential* elements to remove. If they do not remove from one of the endpoints of the list, the list becomes effectively partitioned into two lists.

Of course, there is a "regular" version of the game where the last player to remove an element wins, and the "misere" version where the last player to remove an element loses.

Comment: At least the regular version has the same strategy as ordinary nim. To see this, note that if $b+c<a$, then the XOR of the binary representations of $b$ and $c$ will be strictly smaller than that of $a$. For the misere as well: you follow the same strategy as in the regular case until your opponent presents you a single row. Now you take all but one item from that row.

Comment: This sounds like an octal game with the octal code 0.77777... -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian Goette and Max Alekseyev together answered this question almost completely.

The game you describe is equivalent to the [Octal Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game) "$0.7777\ldots$". I do not believe it has another name.

Under normal play, it is easy to see that a single list of $n$ objects is equivalent (in the sense of the Sprague-Grundy theory) to a Nim heap of size $n$: By induction all the moves that don't split up the list are to the Nim heaps of size $<n$. And as Sebastian Goette points out, if $b+c<a$ then $b\oplus c<a$, so that a Nim heap of size $n$ won't appear among the options.

Since the same is so similar to Nim, the misère play should be similar as well. You should play as in normal-play Nim until your prescribed move would leave only lists of size 1, and then make a move which leaves your opponent an odd number of such lists.